# Front end displaying all lines as dashed lines

Tags: front-end, bugs, linux, ubuntu

**Bug introduced in 10.0.1 and fixed in 10.0.2**

---

Recently I've installed *Mathematica* 10.0 on my Ubuntu 14.4

Now I have some problems with its front-end, in particular it shows all lines as dashed ones (including lines on the right which stand for cells  and cell groups).

Has someone ever had such an experience? I'm wondering whether it is because of wrong installation or some front-end packages are missed or smth

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

Reinstallation doesn't help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Linux-specific bug that has been fixed in Mathematica 10.0.2 and later.